# optimization select distinct query

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

How can i optimize this query, 
how to rewrite a request through exists:

```
select DISTINCT 
        p.SBJ_ID, 
    nvl(l.ATTR,c.CODE) as ATTR, 
        l.VALUE
from T_TRFPRMLST p,
       T_CMSATTR_LINK l, 
       C_SBJCONCEPT c
where l.SBJ_ID(+) = p.SBJ_ID
  and p.sbj_id = c.ID;
```

Comment: Optimization always starts with analyzing the execution plan. please share it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `ANSI` style join syntax, first of all.

Now, Coming to your question, according to my knowledge `NVL` perform worse when working with large data sets.

So how can we achieve the same functionality? -- We can use `DECODE` or `CASE WHEN`.

Among these two also, `CASE WHEN` will be better when it comes to performance.

Compare the execution plan of query mentioned in your question and the execution plan of the following query and you will definitely find the difference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.SBJ_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN L.ATTR IS NOT NULL THEN L.ATTR
        ELSE C.CODE
    END AS ATTR,
    L.VALUE
FROM
    T_TRFPRMLST P
    JOIN C_SBJCONCEPT C ON ( P.SBJ_ID = C.ID )
    LEFT JOIN T_CMSATTR_LINK L ON ( P.SBJ_ID = L.SBJ_ID);
```

Please make sure that `PKs` and `FKs` are properly created and proper `indexes` are also available as `indexes` are created mainly for performance.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `exists` here, because you are using more than 1 table columns in `select`.
And I understand you should use standard `join` keyword when joining tables.

```
select DISTINCT 
        p.SBJ_ID, 
    nvl(l.ATTR,c.CODE) as ATTR, 
        l.VALUE
from T_TRFPRMLST p
join T_CMSATTR_LINK l
  on l.SBJ_ID = p.SBJ_ID 
join C_SBJCONCEPT c
  on p.sbj_id = c.ID;
```

I might be wrong in left/right as I am not much frequent with (+).

Hope this helps.